# How to create Class Table and ProgId Table in .msm file using Windows Installer XML

Tags: installation, wix

As I mentioned in the title I need to do reverse engineering with a .msm file, this MSM file contains a class table and a progId table and I can't find any simple code example of how to do it.
If I put class and progId in "File", I only get a new entry in the registry table. That someone could give me a simple example but with all the Wix?

Comment: FWIW, WiX trys to avoid those tables in favor of the Registry table which can express the same thing but without some of the glitches of MSI.

Comment: This explains why everything ends up in the register table.

Comment: Absent some documented need to use the COM tables, the Registry table approach that WiX takes is the best default behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Use `Class` and `ProgId` elements with their `Advertise` attributes set to `yes`.

The [WiX `Class` doc](https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/xsd/wix/class/) says:

> Set this value to "yes" in order to create a normal Class table row.

Comment: Unfortunately it did not work ;/ but thanks for help;)

Comment: This works for me with a little tweaking. It looks like this 13 year old issue is still there. https://sourceforge.net/p/wix/bugs/2036/

Answer (score 0):

I used IsWiX and heat to generate this short POC.  Heat originally authored the Class element as a child of the File element but that isn't allowed when setting Advertise to yes like Bob said to do.  I used some random Windows OCX file because I don't author COM components these days.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <?define ComponentRules="OneToOne"?>
  <!-- SourceDir instructs IsWiX the location of the directory that contains files for this merge module -->
  <?define SourceDir="..\Deploy"?>
  <Module Id="MergeModule1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0">
    <Package Id="ae2940bf-2a96-409f-8828-43732e8eec3d" Manufacturer="MergeModule1" InstallerVersion="200" />
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="MergeRedirectFolder">
          <Component Id="owc1342753EC14FB934098148748894FC8C" Guid="cb00efc4-e09b-8162-9ee7-2f0d2982bab0" >
              <Class Id="{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}" Context="InprocServer32" Description="ScriptControl Object" ThreadingModel="apartment" Version="1.0" Programmable="yes" Control="yes" Advertise="yes">
                  <ProgId Id="MSScriptControl.ScriptControl.1" Description="ScriptControl Object">
                      <ProgId Id="MSScriptControl.ScriptControl" Description="ScriptControl Object" />
                      <ProgId Id="ScriptControl" Description="ScriptControl Object" />
                  </ProgId>
              </Class>
              <File Id="owf1342753EC14FB934098148748894FC8C" Source="$(var.SourceDir)\msscript.ocx" KeyPath="yes">
                  <TypeLib Id="{0E59F1D2-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}" Description="Microsoft Script Control 1.0" HelpDirectory="MergeRedirectFolder" Language="0" MajorVersion="1" MinorVersion="0" Advertise="yes">
                      <Interface Id="{0E59F1D3-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}" Name="IScriptControl" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{70841C6F-067D-11D0-95D8-00A02463AB28}" Name="IScriptModuleCollection" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{70841C70-067D-11D0-95D8-00A02463AB28}" Name="IScriptModule" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{70841C71-067D-11D0-95D8-00A02463AB28}" Name="IScriptProcedureCollection" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{70841C73-067D-11D0-95D8-00A02463AB28}" Name="IScriptProcedure" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{70841C78-067D-11D0-95D8-00A02463AB28}" Name="IScriptError" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020424-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                      <Interface Id="{8B167D60-8605-11D0-ABCB-00A0C90FFFC0}" Name="DScriptControlSource" ProxyStubClassId32="{00020420-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}" />
                  </TypeLib>

              </File>
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A52-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A53-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\Implemented Categories\{0DE86A57-2BAA-11CF-A229-00AA003D7352}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED4-2438-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\Implemented Categories\{40FC6ED5-2438-11CF-A3DB-080036F12502}" Value="" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\MiscStatus\1" Value="132499" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\MiscStatus" Value="0" Type="string" Action="write" />
              <RegistryValue Root="HKCR" Key="CLSID\{0E59F1D5-1FBE-11D0-8FF2-00A0D10038BC}\ToolboxBitmap32" Value="[#owf1342753EC14FB934098148748894FC8C],102" Type="string" Action="write" />
          </Component>
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Custom" />
  </Module>
</Wix>
```

[image: Orca]